# null object reference while call other compenet function

Tags: apache-flex

I have create the following function in component A(which is productDetailComp)

```
        public  function  createProductDetailItem(productdetail:Productdetail):void{



            productdetailService.createProductdetail(productdetail);
            productdetailService.commit();



        }
```

and in the component B, I call the function via

var productdetail:Productdetail = new Productdetail();

productDetailComp.createProductDetailItem(productdetail);

but, why the following error pop up while invoking the createProductDetailItem() function? Need to create a instance for the function or the component productDetailComp??

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at productDetailComp/onEdit()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productDetailComp.mxml:80]
    at productDetailComp/__button2_click()[C:\Users\School\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\FYPadminSideV3\src\productDetailComp.mxml:250]

Comment: how to trace where the "Object" is ? =.='

Comment: Impossible to tell from the information you provide? Please give us more info/code.

Comment: Are you created productDetailComp and productdetailService?

Comment: The productdetailService is a php service, and behind it (.createProductdetail()) is a function that live in the php service.

Comment: In the Component A I create a function that can invoke this php service. and In other Component B, I try to call this function and doing some php service.

Comment: but I dont know why I cann't call this function, and dont know what null object reference means?

Comment: I know the problem is 
just create a instance to the service call and that will be ok.

like

var pds:ProductdetailService = new ProductdetailService();
    pds.createProductdetail(productdetail);
    pds.commit();